# ORA-00904: "from$_subquery$_014"."column_name": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

After the migration of my oracle db im getting below error:

```
ORA-00904: "from$_subquery$_014"."TRN_TERMINAL_SOFTWARE_VERSION": invalid identifier
```

below is my query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(trn_amt)   AS amount,
      SUM(trn_count) AS COUNT ,
      timetype       AS period ,
      seq ,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vw.seq DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM
      YSD_STORE_FORWARD_V vw
    INNER JOIN store_dimension std                 ON vw.stm_id=std.std_id
    INNER JOIN card_type_dimension ctd             ON vw.CTD_CARD_ABBV=ctd.CTD_CARD_ABBV
    INNER JOIN STPLDBTEMP.store_group_relation sgr ON std.STD_ID= sgr.sgr_store_id
    INNER JOIN location_dimension ld               ON ld.lod_id=std.std_location_id
WHERE
  start_date BETWEEN 20170405 AND 20170405
AND std.std_corp_id    ='1939'
AND sgr.sgr_sgm_id     ='2160'
AND ctd.CTD_CARD_ABBV IN ('VE','VI','VS','VD','AX','AE','MD','MC','MF','XX'
  ,'DB','JB','NV','DS','EB','EBC','EBF','EBW','VF','VG','WX','DC','GF','PL'
  ,'PW','NM','BG','GC','FL','FO','FT','FW','INV','IV','IN','CP')
AND LD.LOD_COUNTRY_ID = 1
GROUP BY
  timetype ,
  seq
ORDER BY
  4
```

);

I'm not using column in my query still I'm getting this error, Please help me out `YSD_STORE_FORWARD_V` its a View which is using materialized view contain `TRN_TERMINAL_SOFTWARE_VERSION` column but my working is fine.

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT * FROM YSD_STORE_FORWARD_V`? Do the columns match up with the columns you are using in the above query?

Comment: A couple of questions -> 1. Does this object exists: `TRN_TERMINAL_SOFTWARE_VERSION `? (try desc `TRN_TERMINAL_SOFTWARE_VERSION `) 2. Does your user (running the query above) has `READ` privilege on it? 3. Does it reside on the same schema and on the same database?

Comment: Does removing the redundant subquery make any difference? Or at least moving the `order by` outside? The execution plan might help identify where that Oracle-generated subquery name fits in to the overall query. Sounds like it *might* be a parser bug though.... Which version is this, and which version did you migrate from, and how?

Comment: SELECT * FROM YSD_STORE_FORWARD_V is i run this query it gives me a result.

Comment: 1. Does this object exists: TRN_TERMINAL_SOFTWARE_VERSION ? (try desc TRN_TERMINAL_SOFTWARE_VERSION )
 ans: yes, In My VIEWS and MATERIALIZED VIEWS

 2. Does your user (running the query above) has READ privilege on it? 
ANS: YES.

3. Does it reside on the same schema and on the same database?
ANS: YES

Comment: Oracle Eneterprise db 11.0.2 we took new import on my local Environement

Comment: when i convert view to table it works fine, but i cant convert it to table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Oracle 11.2.0.4, it appears randomly in queries using subqueries or ansi join.

In my case I found the root cause: It was caused when I did a expdp from 11.2.0.4 and the schema has MATERIALIZED VIEWS. Then I did an impdp in other DataBase (10g, 11g and even 12c). Some kind of diccionary problem causes the bug.

I solved doing this:

1. EXPDP excluding MATERIALIZED_VIEWS
2. IMPDP. There were some errors related to MATERIALIZED_VIEW objects, wich were ignored.
3. Create manually all the MATERIALIZED_VIEW objects.
4. Recompile all objects in database, using “$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql”

This is an extract of the bug documentation:

> **Bug 17551261  ORA-904 "from$_subquery$_003". with query 
>   rewrite**
>
> This note gives a brief overview of bug 17551261.
>   The content was last updated on: 21-FEB-2014
>
> **Affects:**
>
> Product (Component)   Oracle Server (Rdbms)
>
> Range of versions believed to be affected Versions BELOW 12.1
>
> Versions confirmed as being affected  **11.2.0.4**
>
> Platforms affected    Generic (all / most platforms affected)
>
> It is believed to be a regression in default behaviour thus:
>   Regression introduced in 11.2.0.4
>
> **Fixed:** The fix for 17551261 is first
>   included in   •   12.1.0.1 (Base Release)
>
> **Description** This
>   problem is introduced in 11.2.0.4 by the fix for bug 14049796 .
>
> If an ORA-904 similar to the following is raised:
>   *ORA-00904: "from$_subquery$_003"."SUBSCRIBER_SID": invalid identifier* 
>   from a SQL statement using ANSI joins,  then it may be a case of this
>   bug if all of the following are true:
>
> 1) Summary rewrite is used
>
> 2) fix to bug:14049796 present (this fix is included in 11.2.0.4)
>
> 3) The errorstack includes kkogvcd() and kkqsgen()
>
> **Workaround**  Disable query rewrite

Comment: But Im getting this Error in Normal Query too, Which is Running fine on my old version i.e 11.2.0.1 but getting error in new version 11.2.0.4

Comment: Did you try importing again all the schema excluding materialized views? After that, you have to create the materialized views in separates scripts, and compile all objects.